# All pairs/Cartesian multiplication of iterators in rust

Tags: rust

crustaceans!

This is my attempt at creating an `all_pairs` operation for rust iterators. The code has to generate a new iterator which, when iterated, produces all pairs of elements from each iterator, so for example:

```rust
assert_eq!(
    vec![1, 2].iter().all_pairs(vec!['a', 'b'].iter()).collect::<Vec<_>>(),
    vec![(&1, &'a'), (&1, &'b'), (&2, &'a'), (&2, &'b')]
);
```

Here's the code. Since we need to return each element multiple times, we need one Iterator to be cloneable so we can generate new copies of it (instead of resetting, which iterators don't support) for each element of the other; we also need the other iterator's elements to be cloneable as well since each element must be returned multiple times. Note that this plays really well with any iterator that returns immutable references, since those are cloneable by default.

Any comments are welcome.

```rust
use std::iter::Iterator;

pub struct AllPairs<TI: Iterator, UI: Iterator + Clone> {
    iter1: TI,
    iter2: UI,
    iter2_clone: Option<UI>,
    iter1_val: Option<TI::Item>,
}

impl<TI: Iterator, UI: Iterator + Clone> Iterator for AllPairs<TI, UI>
where
    TI::Item: Clone,
{
    type Item = (TI::Item, UI::Item);

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if let None = self.iter1_val {
            self.iter1_val = self.iter1.next();
            self.iter2_clone = Some(self.iter2.clone());
        }

        match &self.iter1_val {
            None => None,
            Some(iter1_val) => match self.iter2_clone.as_mut().unwrap().next() {
                None => {
                    self.iter1_val = None;
                    self.next()
                }
                Some(iter2_val) => Some((iter1_val.clone(), iter2_val)),
            },
        }
    }
}

pub trait IteratorExt: Iterator {
    fn all_pairs<UI: Iterator + Clone>(self, other: UI) -> AllPairs<Self, UI>
    where
        Self: Sized,
        Self::Item: Clone,
    {
        AllPairs::<Self, UI> {
            iter1: self,
            iter2: other,
            iter2_clone: None,
            iter1_val: None,
        }
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator> IteratorExt for I {}
```